# Dropdown value not set on Page load

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

Dropdown value is populated when I initialize the page but the value is not set.

I have a listing page when I click on any record, it navigates to new page and passes the ID of selected record.

I populate the dropdown value on the `InitializeController` event, set the dropdown value after getting the details of the selected record id:

```
this.initializeController = function () {
        var productType = new Object();
        ajaxService.ajaxPost(productType, "api/ProductTypeService/GetProductType", this.getProductTypeOnSuccess, this.getProductTypeOnError);

var productID = ($routeParams.id || "");

if (productID != "") {
            x.productID = productID;
            var product = new Object();
            product.productID = productID;
            ajaxService.ajaxPost(product, "api/ProductService/GetProducts", this.getProductOnSuccess, this.getProductOnError);
        }
};
this.getProductOnSuccess = function (response) {
        x.productTypeID = response.productTypeID;
    };


<div ng-controller="productMaintenanceController as x" ng-init="x.initializeController()">
    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <select ng-model="x.productTypeID">
                            <option value="">-- Select Product Type --</option>
                            <option ng-repeat="z in x.productTypes" value="{{z.productTypeID}}" ng-selected="{{z.productTypeID ==x.productTypeID}}">{{z.productTypeName}}</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>
     </div>
```

Comment: I am assuming that the select has nothing in it until your JavaScript executes?  So Angular is handling the two way databind and should in essence handle the select?

Comment: The code is incomplete. What's `x`? What is it bound to? Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: i updated my question